# placeholders in angular reactiveforms controls causing input state as dirty

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, angular-reactive-forms, form-control

In **IE11** - input controls are being signed as **dirty** when they have **placeholder**. As a result - **validators** based on these controls status are being activated. It works perfect on chrome.
See My code:

```
<input type="email" email name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address"  formControlName="Email"
            [ngClass]= "{ 'alert-danger': isInvalid(formControls.Email) }" > 
<div *ngIf="isInvalid(formControls.Email) && formControls.Email.errors.required">
         enter email
</div>
```

and component:

```
isInvalid(formControl : AbstractControl) : boolean
{
  return formControl.invalid && (formControl.dirty || formControl.touched);
}
```

Comment: It seems a known issue and there're similar threads in GitHub. You could refer to [this thread](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16151) and [this thread](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14440). The [official solution](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/29895) is still in progress. You could wait for the Angular official updating the fix of the issue or use [touched and untouched properties](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14440#issuecomment-321289146) as a workaround.

Comment: if your remove placeholder then it will works.. Yes, its known issue